# Unix/Linux - awk - displaying unxpected ! character when viewed in mail; but not in actual file

Tags: unix, awk

I am on AIX; I am processing the input files and generating a .html file using AWK and sending it through mail using /usr/sbin/sendmail;
Strangely there are some parts in .html file where there is **!**
eg: Assume that the .html file contains many lines out of which "account" is also part of it, but when it is sent through mail, the **account** is displayed as **acco!unt**  Please note that the .html file doesn't contain ! character.  But when the report is viewed in Outlook, it contains ! characters.  Even if the .html file is replaced with .xls (excel), the ! is till present in the mail.  But not present in the actual file.  Can you please let me know how to remove this.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code and generated output/html.

Comment: Hi Vipin Kumar, I am in remote desktop and cannot copy/paste it.  But here is process.. for i in $(ls *.dat); do; while read line; do ; if [ $line == "abc" ] then echo "account_number" >> output.html;  if [ $line == "xyz" ] then echo "closed_date" >> output.html ....done < $i;   done;  output.html file contains  **account_number** multiple times, but only at random positions ! is getting embedded into them.  This is not specific to "account_number" columns itself, but to other columns too.  Please note that when I open the .html file in Unix, it is without !  But when mail is received it has !

Comment: for loop won't provide much information to solve this query unless until, someone has faced exact issue. I have completed couple of project on AIX+sending html file using sendmail and considering my experience, there will be some mistake in html file generation, possibly you won't see `!` in html file but it is getting printed with a combination of ASCII code.

Comment: Please note that it is being run for multiple files.  Say if output_file1  has ! character at some location; Output_file2 has ! character at other locations.  I really do not understand it.  At times they occur below100 characters in the mail, and at times they occur after 400 characters in the mail.

Comment: In Unix, GNU/Linux below command can print exclamation - 
`$printf "\41\n"
    !`
You need to look for something like this in your script.

Comment: Hi Vipin Kumar, thank you for your attention.  I was using "echo ``cat output.html``"  statement.  Changing it to "cat output.html" resolved the issue.  Thank you.